# Changing several CSS Ids to Classes

Tags: javascript, css

I have some CSS ids that run some transitions, I want this transition to run more than just the one element...I try to convert them to classes, but something messes up and I'm not sure what is happening. An example of how my CSS ids look:

```css
#transition {}
#transition.flipped {}
#transition figure {}
#transition .front {}
#transition .back {}
```

If I change them too

```css
.transition {}
.flipped {}
.transition figure {}
.front {}
.back {}
```

I change the javascript `getElementbyId` to `getElementsByClassName`. The transition doesn't work and the JS console shows no errors.

HTML from comment

```
<div class="transition">
   <figure class="front">
      <img src="img/work/0002.png">
   </figure>
   <figure class="back">
      <img src="img/work/0007.png">
   </figure>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var init = function() {
    var trans = document.getElementsByClassName('transition');

    document.getElementsByClassName('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        trans.toggleClassName('flipped');
    }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Comment: Do any of the elements have those classes?

Comment: `GetElementsByClassName` should be `getElementsByClassName` and it returns an array so your JS would either need to loop or select the first item by adding `[0]` after it.

Comment: This probably isnt the case but did you change id to class??

Comment: I missed typed in my post...I did use getElementsByClassName.

I did change the id to class

Comment: @misplacedme yeah in the html I have
<div class="transition">
<figure class="front"><img src="img/work/0002.png"></figure>
<figure class="back"><img src="img/work/0007.png"></figure>
</div>

Comment: well remember that getElementsByClassName isn't supported as much in IE as getElementByID. Mind if I ask the other question....are you opposed to using the jquery framework?

Comment: Ok. Show the markup related to the issue. In that way the number of possible bugs will get narrow. Just the HTML involved on those classes and nearby elements.

Comment: Show your Javascript that performs the transitions, and explain in more detail how it "doesn't work".

Comment: JS code:
var init = function() {
 var trans = document.getElementsByClassName('transition');
 
 document.getElementsByClassName('flip').addEventListener( 'click', function() {
  trans.toggleClassName('flipped');
 }, false);
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

The button I press to start the transition do nothing. No changes happen on the page and JS console shows no errors.

I'm new to all of this so I'm not sure about using JQuery.

Comment: @Morokiane Please stop trying to put code in comments. Don't you see the "edit" button below the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array. You can loop through that array if you want, but an easier option would be to include jQuery.

First, add this to your html file, as far down as you can:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Then, in a separate script file included below that, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var trans = $('.transition');

    $('.flip').click(function() {
        trans.toggleClass('flipped');
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/XDRDH/)**

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` returns a single DOM element.

`getElementsByClassName` return an array of DOM elements.

You can't set events on an array; you need to set it on each element individually.